# Loading state for single reducer in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have problem using only one loader state for my reducer in redux. The goal is to make sure each different button have 'loading...' before they hit the api, now the problem is all buttons will display 'loading...'

I created a demo for this problem
https://codesandbox.io/s/jlq103oq1v

Comment: You're going to have to specify different ```loading``` flag for each fetch action.. ```isResetting```, ```isApproving```

Comment: @Varinder means I have to do it manually for all button?

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate loading states, Currently you only have one loading state and you take your decision based on that, but you buttons need to identify if the loading sstate is meant for them or someone else. You can either renaming your loading states to `approve_loading` and `reset_loading` and use them like

```
@connect(state => state.items, { approveItem, resetItem })
export default class Items extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>status: {this.props.item.status}</div>
        <button onClick={() => this.props.resetItem()}>
          {this.props.reset_loading ? "loading..." : "Reset"}
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => this.props.approveItem()}>
          {this.props.approve_loading ? "loading..." : "Approve"}
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**[working codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/9j50n14q6r)**

or structure your reducer differently,

[**working sandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/znz59k714p) for the same

Comment: can't open your codesandbox, error of `Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined
`